# Is it a pure function if it reads some data from outside rather than parameters?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

In the book of "functional programming in Scala", it gives some examples about side-effects, like:

- Modifying a variable
- Modifying a data structure in place
- Setting a field on an object
- Throwing an exception or halting with an error  Printing to the console or reading user input
- Reading from or writing to a file
- Drawing on the screen

My question is, is reading some data from outside rathen than the parameters makes the function impure?

E.g.

```
val name = "Scala"

def upcase() = name.toUpperCase
```

Is the `upcase` function pure or not?

---

Edit: as per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31377452/342235, my "function" is not actually function, it's a method, so I give a function version of it, and ask the same question:

```
val name = "Scala"

val upcase: () => String = () => name.toUpperCase
```

Comment: As `name` itself is immutable and all calls to `upcase` return the same output, `def upcase` is pure. No variables are modified, a new immutable object is created and is returned.

Comment: What matters is the function, not how it's expressed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading from *immutable* data is not impure; the function will still return the same value every time. If `name` were a `var` then that function would be impure, since something external could change `name`, so multiple calls to `upcase()` might evaluate to different values.

(Of course it might be possible to e.g. alter `name` through reflection. Properly we can only talk about purity with respect to some notion of what kind of functions are allowed to call a given function, and what kind of side effects we consider to be equivalent)

It's worth noting that your function is not pure because `toUpperCase` is not pure; it depends on the system's default Locale, and may produce different results on different systems (e.g. on a Turkish system, `"i".toUpperCase == "İ"`). You should always pass an explicit `Locale`, e.g. `def upcase() = name.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH)`; then the function will be pure.

Comment: Thanks for pointing my problem with `toUpperCase`, never noticed that!

Answer (score -1):

Interestingly, the answer is "No", but not for the reason you think it is. Your `upcase` is *not* a pure function. It is, however, pure, but it is a method, not a function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I just updated the question to add the 'function' version

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the context?

Comment: That's a bit pedantic.

Comment: @dcastro It really isn't.  It is very important in Scala to differentiate between functions and methods, *particularly* in the context of purity..  Methods have a hidden parameter (**this**).  Functions which call methods may very well inadvertently invoke side effects.